# Statement return wrong values

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I have a JAVA Application which uses `HSQLDB`. There is a table called `'tblUser'` containing a column `bigint` type called `'tongHH'`.  If I use the HSQLDB DatabaseManager to run the following query:

```
select sum(tongHH) from tblUser.
```

The DBM returns the right values
If I use the following JAVA Code to read out this data with the same query, java always prints wrong value. i getting 65 and i expected 3905

```
public int getParentID(String query) {
    int a = 0;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
       conn = MyConection.getConnection();
       Statement st = conn.createStatement();
       rs = st.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()){
    a=rs.getByte(1);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {         
            MyConection.closeConnection(conn, null, rs);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
return a;
}
```

Comment: What value are you expecting?  What incorrect value are you getting?

Comment: you want to return an int, but when you read the value from recordset, you are using getByte(1), should be getInt

Comment: in DB i get 3905
in java return 65

Comment: thanks you!! it run. i'm just a beginer @RusselYang

Comment: @TrungXốp Please edit your question to include the value you're getting and the value you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overflowing the `byte` you are attempting to retrieve from the `ResultSet`.

The value `3905` as an `int` is:

```
00000000 00000000 00001111 01000001
```

Getting the value as a `byte` only keeps the last 8 bits, or

```
01000001
```

which is `65`.

Call [the `getInt` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt-int-) instead.

Comment: thank u.I understand. i'm just beginer. but alway it return right values until i use sum()

Answer (score 0):

you want to return an int, but when you read the value from recordset, you are using getByte(1), should be getInt(1)